# Can the -eq function compare against a variable

Tags: powershell, variables, comparison

It appears that -eq can only compare against a literal. I am trying to compare against a variable like this. This code does not work

```
> $macaddr = ((getmac /v /fo csv | findstr ASIX) -split "," )[2]
> $echo $macaddr
"00-01-02-03-04-05"
> $adapter = Get-NetAdapter | ? {$_.MacAddress -eq $macaddr}
> echo $adapter
>
```

If I change the comparison to a literal, it appears to work fine.

```
> $adapter = Get-NetAdapter | ? {$_.MacAddress -eq "00-01-02-03-04-05"}
> echo $adapter
Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet 3                ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethe...      12 Up           00-01-02-03-04-05       100 Mbps
```

How should I handle the comparison?

Comment: You've captured the literal `"`'s around the mac address, so you're effectively making the comparison `'00-01-02-03-04-05' -eq '"00-01-02-03-04-05"'`, which is obviously not true

Comment: It's probably because you're comparing a single value to an array (`$macaddr`) or, the string isn't just the MACAddress returned. Can you post the results of `$macaddr`? Also, if you're converting to csv, you can pipe to `ConvertFrom-Csv` to return an object you can use instead: `getmac /fo csv /v | ConvertFrom-Csv`/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/fo csv` option makes `getmac.exe` quote the mac addresses, so the literal string value is not `00-01-02-03-04-05`, but `"00-01-02-03-04-05"` (including the quotation marks), and they're obviously different:

```
> '00-01-02-03-04-05' -eq '"00-01-02-03-04-05"'
False
```

Either use `ConvertFrom-Json` to re-parse the output:

```
$macAddr = getmac /v /fo csv |ConvertFrom-Csv |Where-Object 'Network Adapter' -like '*ASIX*' |Select-Object -Expand 'Physical Address'
```

Or use the `Trim()` method to remove the quotation marks from the raw output:

```
$macaddr = ((getmac /v /fo csv | findstr ASIX) -split "," )[2].Trim('"')
```